# Пустой $_POST после AJAX запроса

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Есть форма с которой я отправляю `value` `input`-ов в `php`. Делаю я это `ajax` запросом но почему-то, когда я обращаюсь в `php` файле к `$_POST` - он пустой.

Вот форма и запрос:

```js
$('#form li input').click(function select_lang() {
  var lang = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/header.php",
    data: {
      'lang': lang
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <form method="post" action="javascript:void(null);" id="form" onsubmit="select_lang()">
    <li>
      <input type="button" name="lang" id="first" value="Hello">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" name="lang" id="second" value="Bye">
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Вот `header.php`:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['lang'];    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в js коде - onsubmit означает, что js-код будет выполняться при нажатии не на простую кнопку, а на type=submit
Нужно переписать код.

Answer (score 0):

Неверное обращение к переменным окружения. Верно так:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['lang'];
```

Кроме этого, непонятно что должна делать

```
var lang = $(this).attr('id');
```

В настоящий момент значение будет пустым, т.к. значение атрибута id кнопок не установлено.

Comment: А как быть, если после  закрытия `php` идет `html` код?

Comment: Значит нужно закрыть ?>. Ошибка в том, что написано $POST вместо  $_POST. Ну ещё и с js частью очевидные проблемы.

Comment: Не заметил что не прописал `id`(а пост я поправил, в коде было правильно написано) Суть такая, я по клику на какую-то из кнопок по её `id` я определяю что это была за кнопка и отправляю её `id` в `php` для каких-то действий.